# Timeouts sending out HTTP requests in Python Functions apps on Azure

Tags: python, http, ssl, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

As of recently, multiple API calls executed in the Azure function app environment have broken down. The responses of these calls are simply Timeouts, which are difficult to debug.

for a simple request like so: `requests.get(url, timeout=100)`, the traceback is as follows:

```
ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<api_host>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: <endpoint>
(Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

Without the timeout the function app simply hangs until it times out.

When the azure function runs locally, the connection is established perfectly fine. Also, not all api calls in azure are broken, but just some of them. I suspect i has something to do with TLS/SSL which may be different in the Azure enviroment, but I cannot figure it out.

The fuction apps are running on runtime version 4.23.00